# CPU usage is 100%

Tags: 16.04, updates, performance, intel, cpu

Intel i5-7200U Kaby Lake.
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

2 of my 4 processing cores are 100% loaded, even if no processes are running. The load can pass on other cores, but there is always two 100% loaded cores. The issue occurred recently. There is no such issue on Windows 10 on the exact same PC (see screenshots). Maybe there was some update (e.g. to fix Meltdown or Spectre), which loads my CPU.

Please advise.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, I already looked. All processes show 0% CPU usage.

Comment: I also looked in top command. 
It seems that some systemd command consumes the CPU time. Please see the following log:

2008 root      20   0  584716  19648  10868 S 200.0  0.1  73:37.85 systemd

Comment: Figured out that it was a crypto miner built in game 2048 (downloaded from Ubuntu Software). 

Created an issue by this link:
https://github.com/canonical-websites/snapcraft.io/issues/651

Here is the log of the command sudo lsof -p 2008 -n:
https://pastebin.com/spH358jC

If you know some better way to report the issue, please adives.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that it was a crypto miner built in game 2048 (downloaded from Ubuntu Software).

Created an issue by this link:
https://github.com/canonical-websites/snapcraft.io/issues/651

Here is the log of the command sudo lsof -p 2008 -n:
https://pastebin.com/spH358jC

If you know some better way to report the issue, please advise.